# Problem with freeing up memory (for a class containing a custom vector)

Tags: c++, object, hex

```
#include "../include/Hex.hpp"

int main()
{
    Vector<unsigned char> a{'1', '2', '3', '4'};
    Vector<unsigned char> b = a;
    b.resize(2);
    a.resize(6);
    a = b;
}
```

If I'm just working with a vector, then valgrind writes that the memory is being released correctly, no matter what methods of custom vector I use
But:

```
#include "../include/Hex.hpp"

int main()
{
    Hex a("A1");
    Hex b(a);
    Hex c = a;
    std::cout << c;
}
```

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck ./main
==9066== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9066== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9066== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9066== Command: ./main
==9066== 
==9066== Invalid write of size 2
==9066==    at 0x48529E3: memmove (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9066==    by 0x10C5CE: unsigned char* std::__copy_move<false, true, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m<unsigned char>(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066==    by 0x10C58A: unsigned char* std::__copy_move_a2<false, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*>(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066==    by 0x10C4AD: unsigned char* std::__copy_move_a1<false, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*>(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066==    by 0x10C271: unsigned char* std::__copy_move_a<false, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*>(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066==    by 0x10BF58: unsigned char* std::copy<unsigned char const*, unsigned char*>(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066==    by 0x10B968: Vector<unsigned char, Allocator<unsigned char> >::operator=(Vector<unsigned char, Allocator<unsigned char> > const&) (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066==    by 0x10A8F9: Hex::Hex(Hex const&) (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066==    by 0x10B3B4: main (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066==  Address 0x4dddd10 is 0 bytes after a block of size 0 alloc'd
==9066==    at 0x4849013: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9066==    by 0x10BD69: Allocator<unsigned char>::Allocate(unsigned long) (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066==    by 0x10B6BB: Vector<unsigned char, Allocator<unsigned char> >::Vector() (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066==    by 0x10A8DE: Hex::Hex(Hex const&) (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066==    by 0x10B3B4: main (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066== 
==9066== Invalid read of size 1
==9066==    at 0x10AFCF: operator<<(std::ostream&, Hex&) (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066==    by 0x10B3E0: main (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066==  Address 0x4dddd51 is 1 bytes after a block of size 0 alloc'd
==9066==    at 0x4849013: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9066==    by 0x10BD69: Allocator<unsigned char>::Allocate(unsigned long) (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066==    by 0x10B6BB: Vector<unsigned char, Allocator<unsigned char> >::Vector() (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066==    by 0x10A8DE: Hex::Hex(Hex const&) (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066==    by 0x10B3CA: main (in /home/aleksandr/LABS-OOP/OOPLab2/tests/main)
==9066== 
A1==9066== 
==9066== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9066==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 1 blocks
==9066==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 5 frees, 73,732 bytes allocated
==9066== 
==9066== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9066==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 1 blocks
==9066==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9066==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9066==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9066==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9066== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==9066== 
==9066== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==9066== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

note that if the Hex object is created by the copy constructor, then the memory is freed normally, so 6 allocs ,5 frees

Hex.hpp

```
#ifndef HEX_HPP
#define HEX_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include "Vector.hpp"

class Hex
{
public:
    Vector<unsigned char> hex;
public:
    Hex();
    Hex(const std::string& num);
    Hex(const size_t & n, const unsigned char &t = 0);
    Hex(const Hex& other);
    Hex(Hex&& other) noexcept;
    Hex(const std::initializer_list<unsigned char> &t);

    virtual ~Hex() noexcept;

    int hexToDecimal(char symb);
    char decimalToHex(int dec);

    bool operator>=(const Hex &r) const;
    bool operator<=(const Hex &r) const;
    bool operator<(const Hex &r) const;
    bool operator>(const Hex &r) const;
    bool operator==(const Hex &r) const;
    bool operator!=(const Hex &r) const;
    void operator=(const Hex& other);
    Hex operator+(const Hex& other);
    Hex operator-(const Hex& other);

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out,  Hex &x);
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in,  Hex &x);
};

#include "../src/Hex.cpp"

#endif //HEX_HPP
```

Hex.cpp

```
#include "../include/Hex.hpp"

Hex::Hex() {}

Hex::Hex(const std::string& num)
{
    size_t n = num.size();
    hex.resize(n);
    size_t j = n - 1;
    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < n  ; ++i) {
        if(num[j] >= '0' && num[j] <= '9') {
            hex[i] = num[j];
        }
        else if(num[j] >= 'A' && num[j] <= 'F') {
            hex[i] = num[j];
        }
        else {
            throw "Invalid number";
        }
        --j;
    }
}

Hex::Hex(const size_t & n, const unsigned char &t) 
{
    if(t >= '0' && t <= '9') {
    }
    else if(t >= 'A' && t <= 'F') {
    }
    else {
        throw "Invalid number";
    }
    this->hex.resize(n);
    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i) {
        hex[i] = t;
    }
}

Hex::Hex(Hex&& other) noexcept
{
    this->hex = other.hex;
}

Hex::Hex(const Hex& other)
{
    this->hex = other.hex;
}

Hex::Hex(const std::initializer_list<unsigned char> &t)
{
    hex.resize(t.size());
    int i = t.size();
    for (auto it = t.begin(); it != t.end() ; ++it) {
        unsigned char p = *it;
        --i;
        if(p >= '0' && p <= '9') {
            hex[i] = p;
        }
        else if(p >= 'A' && p <= 'F') {
            hex[i] = p;
        }
        else {
            throw "Invalid number";
        }
    }
}

int Hex::hexToDecimal(char symb)
{
    if(symb >= '0' && symb <= '9') {
        return symb - '0';
    }
    else if(symb >= 'A' && symb <= 'F') {
        return symb - 'A' + 10;
    } else {
        throw "Invalid number";
    }
}

char Hex::decimalToHex(int dec)
{
    if(dec >= 0 && dec <= 9) {
        return dec + '0';
    }
    else {
        return dec - 10 + 'A';
    }
}

Hex Hex::operator+(const Hex& other)
{
    int carry = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    Hex temp;
    int j = std::max(other.hex.size(), this->hex.size());
    temp.hex.resize(j);
    while(i < j) {
        if(i < other.hex.size()) {
            sum += hexToDecimal(other.hex[i]);
        }
        if(i < this->hex.size()) {
            sum += hexToDecimal(this->hex[i]);
        }
        sum += carry;
        carry = 0;
        if(sum >= 16) {
            carry = 1;
            sum %= 16;
        }
        temp.hex[i] = decimalToHex(sum);
        sum = 0;
        ++i;
    }
    if(carry) {
        temp.hex.push_back(carry + '0');
    }
    return temp;
}

Hex Hex::operator-(const Hex& other)
{
    int takeUnit = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int del2;
    int del1;
    Hex temp;

    int j = std::max(other.hex.size(), this->hex.size());
    while(i < j) {
        if(i < other.hex.size()) {
            del1 = hexToDecimal(other.hex[i]);
        }
        if(i < this->hex.size()) {
            del2 = hexToDecimal(this->hex[i]);
        }
        sum = del2 - del1 - takeUnit;
        takeUnit = 0;
        if(sum < 0 && i+1 != this->hex.size()) {
            takeUnit += 1;
            sum += 16;
        }
        temp.hex.push_back(decimalToHex(sum));
        ++i;
        sum = 0;
    }
    while(temp.hex.back() == '0' && temp.hex.size() > 1) {
        temp.hex.resize(temp.hex.size()-1);
    }
    return temp;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out,  Hex &x) 
{
    for(long long int i = x.hex.size() - 1 ; i >= 0 ; --i) {
        out << x.hex[i];
    }
    return out;
}

void Hex::operator=(const Hex &other) 
{
    hex = other.hex;
}

bool Hex::operator>=(const Hex &r) const
{
    if(this->hex.size() < r.hex.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    else if(this->hex.size() > r.hex.size()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        for(long long int i = this->hex.size() ; i >= 0 ; ++i) {
            if(this->hex.at(i) < r.hex.at(i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

bool Hex::operator<=(const Hex &r) const
{
    if(this->hex.size() < r.hex.size()) {
        return true;
    }
    else if(this->hex.size() > r.hex.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        for(long long int i = this->hex.size() ; i >= 0 ; ++i) {
            if(this->hex.at(i) > r.hex.at(i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

bool Hex::operator<(const Hex &r) const 
{
    return !(*this >= r);
}

bool Hex::operator>(const Hex &r) const 
{
    return !(*this <= r);
}

bool Hex::operator==(const Hex &r) const 
{
    return this->hex == r.hex;
}

bool Hex::operator!=(const Hex &r) const 
{
    return this->hex != r.hex;
}

Hex::~Hex() noexcept 
{
    this->hex.~Vector();
}
```

Vector's destructor

```
template<typename T, typename A>
Vector<T, A>::~Vector() noexcept
{
    if (data_ != nullptr) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            allocator_.Destroy(&data_[i]);
        }
        if (capacity() > 0) {
            allocator_.Deallocate(data(), capacity());
        }
        data_ = nullptr;
    }
    capacity_ = 0;
}
```

the vector destructor works correctly when working with the vector itself, everything breaks only with the hex class

Vector.cpp

```
#include "../include/Vector.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <memory>

template<class T, class A>
Vector<T, A>::Vector() : size_(0), capacity_(0)
{
    data_ = allocator_.Allocate(capacity());
}

template<class T, class A>
Vector<T, A>::Vector(size_t size, const T &value) : size_(size), capacity_(0)
{
    capacity_ = CalculateCapacity(size);
    data_ = allocator_.Allocate(capacity());
    std::fill_n(data(), size, value);
}

template<class T, class A>
Vector<T, A>::Vector(const Vector &other)
{
    this->resize(other.size());
    capacity_ = other.capacity();
    std::copy(other.begin(), other.end(), data());
}

template<class T, class A>
Vector<T, A>::Vector(Vector &&other) noexcept
{
    std::swap(size_, other.size_);
    std::swap(capacity_, other.capacity_);
    std::swap(data_, other.data_);
    other.clear();
}

template<class T, class A>
Vector<T, A>::Vector(const std::initializer_list<T> &init)
{
    size_ = init.size();
    capacity_ = CalculateCapacity(size());
    data_ = allocator_.Allocate(capacity());
    std::copy(init.begin(), init.end(), data());
}

template<typename T, typename A>
Vector<T, A>::~Vector() noexcept
{
    if (data_ != nullptr) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            allocator_.Destroy(&data_[i]);
        }
        if (capacity() > 0) {
            allocator_.Deallocate(data(), capacity());
        }
        data_ = nullptr;
    }
    capacity_ = 0;
}

template<typename T, typename A>
void Vector<T, A>::push_back(T &value)
{
    emplace_back(std::move(value));
}

template<class T, class A>
void Vector<T, A>::push_back(T &&value)
{
    emplace_back(std::move(value));
}

template<typename T, typename A>
void Vector<T, A>::reallocate(size_t minSize)
{
    const size_t newCapacity = CalculateCapacity(minSize + 1);
    T *newData = allocator_.Allocate(newCapacity);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
        allocator_.Construct(&newData[i], data_[i]);
        allocator_.Destroy(&data_[i]);
    }
    if (capacity() > 0) {
        allocator_.Deallocate(data(), capacity());
    }
    capacity_ = newCapacity;
    data_ = newData;
}

template<typename T, typename A>
[[nodiscard]] size_t Vector<T, A>::CalculateCapacity(size_t minSize) const
{
    std::size_t newCapacity;
    if (minSize < capacity()) {
        newCapacity = 1;
    }
    else if (capacity()) {
        newCapacity = capacity();
    }
    else {
        newCapacity = 1;
    }
    while (newCapacity < minSize) {
        if (newCapacity >= std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() - newCapacity) {
            return std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();
        }
        newCapacity *= 2;
    }
    return newCapacity;
}

template<typename T, typename A>
size_t Vector<T, A>::size() const
{
    return size_;
}

template<typename T, typename A>
size_t Vector<T, A>::capacity() const
{
    return capacity_;
}

template<typename T, typename A>
const T *Vector<T, A>::begin() const noexcept
{
    return data_;
}

template<typename T, typename A>
T *Vector<T, A>::begin() noexcept
{
    return data_;
}

template<typename T, typename A>
const T *Vector<T, A>::end() const noexcept
{
    return (data_ + size());
}

template<typename T, typename A>
T *Vector<T, A>::end() noexcept
{
    return (data_ + size());
}

template<typename T, typename A>
const T &Vector<T, A>::back() const
{
    return (data_[size() - 1]);
}

template<typename T, typename A>
T &Vector<T, A>::back()
{
    return (data_[size() - 1]);
}

template<typename T, typename A>
bool Vector<T, A>::empty() const
{
    return (size() == 0);
}

template<typename T, typename A>
const T *Vector<T, A>::data() const noexcept
{
    return data_;
}

template<typename T, typename A>
T *Vector<T, A>::data() noexcept
{
    return data_;
}

template<typename T, typename A>
void Vector<T, A>::reserve(size_t new_capacity)
{
    if (new_capacity > capacity()) {
        reallocate(new_capacity);
        capacity_ = new_capacity;
    }
}

template<typename T, typename A>
void Vector<T, A>::pop_back()
{
    if (size() > 0) {
        allocator_.Destroy(end() - 1);
        --size_;
    }
}

template<typename T, typename A>
void Vector<T, A>::operator=(Vector<T, A> &&other)
{
    std::swap(size_, other.size_);
    std::swap(capacity_, other.capacity_);
    std::swap(data_, other.data_);
    other.clear();
}

template<class T, class Allocator>
Vector<T> &Vector<T, Allocator>::operator=(const Vector<T> &other) {
  size_ = other.size();
  capacity_ = other.capacity();
  this->resize(other.size());
  std::copy(other.begin(), other.end(), data());
  return *this;
}

template<typename T, typename A>
void Vector<T, A>::resize(size_t count)
{
    resize(count, T());
}

template<typename T, typename A>
void Vector<T, A>::resize(size_t count, const T &value)
{
    if (count > capacity()) {
        reserve(count);
        for (size_t i = size(); i < count; ++i) {
            allocator_.Construct(data() + 1, value);
        }
    }
    else if (count < size()) {
        for (size_t i = count; i < size(); ++i) {
            allocator_.Destroy(data() + 1);
        }
    }
    size_ = count;
}

template<typename T, typename A>
template<typename... Args>
void Vector<T, A>::emplace_back(T &&arg, Args &&...args)
{
    if (capacity() == size()) {
        reallocate(capacity() + 1);
    }
    allocator_.Construct(end(), arg);
    ++size_;
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args) > 0) {
        emplace_back(args...);
    }
}

template<class T, class A>
bool Vector<T, A>::operator==(const Vector<T, A> &rhs) const
{
    if (this->size() != rhs.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->size(); ++i) {
        if (this->at(i) != rhs.at(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

template<class T, class A>
bool Vector<T, A>::operator!=(const Vector<T, A> &rhs) const
{
    return !(*this == rhs);
}

template<class T, class A>
T &Vector<T, A>::operator[](size_t pos)
{
    if(pos >= this->size()) {
        throw std::range_error("");
    }
    return data_[pos];
}

template<class T, class Allocator>
const T &Vector<T, Allocator>::operator[](size_t pos) const {
    if(pos >= this->size()) {
        throw std::range_error("");
    }
    return data_[pos];
}

template<class T, class A>
void Vector<T, A>::clear()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        allocator_.Destroy(data() + i);
    }
    size_ = 0;
}

template<class T, class Allocator>
T &Vector<T, Allocator>::at(size_t pos)
{
    if (pos < size()) {
        return data_[pos];
    }
    else {
        throw std::out_of_range("position is out of range");
    }
}

template<class T, class Allocator>
const T &Vector<T, Allocator>::at(size_t pos) const
{
    if (pos < size()) {
        return data_[pos];
    }
    else {
        throw std::out_of_range("position is out of range");
    }
}

template<class T, class A>
bool Vector<T, A>::operator>=(const Vector<T, A> &rhs) const
{
    if(this->size() < rhs.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    else if(this->size() > rhs.size()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        for(size_t i = 0 ; i < this->size() ; ++i) {
            if(this->at(i) < rhs.at(i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

template<class T, class A>
bool Vector<T, A>::operator<=(const Vector<T, A> &rhs) const
{
    if(this->size() < rhs.size()) {
        return true;
    }
    else if(this->size() > rhs.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        for(size_t i = 0 ; i < this->size() ; ++i) {
            if(this->at(i) > rhs.at(i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

template<class T, class A>
bool Vector<T, A>::operator>(const Vector<T, A> &rhs) const
{
    return !(*this <= rhs);
}

template<class T, class A>
bool Vector<T, A>::operator<(const Vector<T, A> &rhs) const
{
    return !(*this >= rhs);
}
```

Vector.h

```
#ifndef VECTOR_HPP
#define VECTOR_HPP
#include "../include/Allocator.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template<class T, class A = Allocator<T>>
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(size_t size, const T &value = T());
    Vector(const Vector &other);
    Vector(Vector &&other) noexcept;
    Vector(const std::initializer_list<T> &init);
    virtual ~Vector() noexcept;
    Vector<T> &operator=(const Vector<T> &other);
    void operator=(Vector<T, A> &&other);
    size_t CalculateCapacity(size_t newSize) const;
    void reallocate(size_t minSize);

    T &at(size_t pos);
    const T &at(size_t pos) const;
    T &operator[](size_t pos);
    const T &operator[](size_t pos) const;
    T &back();
    const T &back() const;
    T *begin() noexcept;
    const T *begin() const noexcept;
    T *end() noexcept;
    const T *end() const noexcept;
    T *data() noexcept;
    const T *data() const noexcept;
    bool operator!=(const Vector<T, A> &rhs) const;
    bool operator==(const Vector<T, A> &rhs) const;
    bool operator>=(const Vector<T, A> &rhs) const;
    bool operator<=(const Vector<T, A> &rhs) const;
    bool operator>(const Vector<T, A> &rhs) const;
    bool operator<(const Vector<T, A> &rhs) const;

    void pop_back();
    bool empty() const;
    size_t size() const;
    size_t capacity() const;
    void reserve(size_t new_cap);
    void clear();
    void push_back(T &item);
    void push_back(T &&item);
    template<class... Args>
    void emplace_back(T &&arg, Args &&...args);
    void resize(size_t count);
    void resize(size_t count, const T &value);

private:
    size_t size_ = 0;
    size_t capacity_ = 0;
    T *data_;
    Allocator<T> allocator_;
};

#include "../src/Vector.cpp"

#endif//VECTOR_HPP
```

Allocator.cpp

```
#include "../include/Allocator.hpp"
template<typename T>
T *Allocator<T>::Allocate(size_t n)
{
    return (T *) (::operator new(n * sizeof(T)));
}

template<typename T>
void Allocator<T>::Deallocate(T *p, size_t n)
{
    delete (p);
}

template<typename T>
template<typename... Args>
void Allocator<T>::Construct(T *p, Args &&...args)
{
    new (p) T(args...);
}

template<typename T>
void Allocator<T>::Destroy(T *p)
{
    p->~T();
}
```

Allocator.hpp

```
#ifndef ALLOCATOR_HPP
#define ALLOCATOR_HPP

#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Allocator
{
private:
    T *pointer;

public:
    T *Allocate(size_t n);
    void Deallocate(T *p, size_t n);
    template<typename... Args>
    void Construct(T *p, Args &&...args);
    void Destroy(T *p);
};

#include "../src/Allocator.cpp"

#endif//ALLOCATOR_HPP
```

Comment: `this->hex.~Vector();` -- Why are you doing this?  Why are you calling the member variable's destructor explicitly?

Comment: The second thing is that you didn't post `Vector`.  If `Vector` is written correctly, then the `Hex` class need not have a user-defined copy constructor or user-defined destructor.  Without needing to write a destructor, the line I pointed out in the first comment need not exist.

Comment: Rule-of-zero: Neither destructor, nor copy/move constructor, nor copy/move assignment operators should be declared for `Hex` at all. (And if it then doesn't work, that means that `Vector` is not implemented correctly.)

Comment: @user17732522, You say that the constructor, for example, copying, should not be used for Hex. I don't understand why, how else can I work with hexadecimal numbers? I don't really understand why I can't use constructors

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I agree it doesn't make sense. But if you don't do this, nothing will change...

Comment: You can use constructors. You *should not* define a destructor. You do not allocate any memory here using `new` that obligates you to do so, and you have no resources to release. **Calling a destructor manually is something you should only do in extremely rare cases.** In fact, you can probably go your entire career without having to do so.

Comment: *I agree it doesn't make sense. But if you don't do this, nothing will change...* -- Which probably means that your `Vector` class is broken, and the issue has nothing to do with `Hex`.  You are basically trying to "fix" the broken Vector class by finagling with `Hex` -- that is not how to fix the problem.

Comment: Seeing manual calls to things like `Destroy` and `Deallocate` is something that stands out as *Super Bad* and likely the cause of many problems. In C++ your goal is to design containers like `Vector` that clean up after themselves, that require zero thought to use, and yet you're either foisting obligations on the instantiator of that resource, or you're overstepping your bounds and calling functions that should likely be `protected`.

Comment: @AleksandrDots You do not need to declare/define any copy/move operations for a class in C++ in order for it to be copyable/movable. They are defined implicitly. A user-definition needs (and should) only exist for classes that manage resources directly (such as `Vector` managing memory allocations) or need unusual behavior. See the [_rule-of-0/3/5_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Knowing these rules is extremely important to write C++ and they should be explained in any introduction to classes in C++.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if `allocator` is not a C++ allocator, but something else entirely. Those have similar functions, but they are, as one would expect, lower-case function names. It's also worth noting that `destroy` was given the boot in C++20.

Comment: @tadman Unlikely to be a standard [_Allocator_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator). The spelling of the member functions isn't correct and the standard allocator interface should be accessed through [`std::allocator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits), not the allocator's member functions directly. (That would make `destroy` available even if not declared as member function, as is the case for `std::allocator` since C++20).

Comment: Let me ask like this: Why are you writing your own `Vector` class? What does it do? How is it implemented? Cause that seems to be the cause of the error. it really seems like when copying your `Vector` you are destroying it.

Comment: @tadman, [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `#include "../include/Allocator.hpp"
template<typename T>
T *Allocator<T>::Allocate(size_t n)
{  return (T *) (::operator new(n * sizeof(T)));
}

template<typename T>
void Allocator<T>::Deallocate(T *p, size_t n)
{
    delete (p);
}

template<typename T>
template<typename... Args>
void Allocator<T>::Construct(T *p, Args &&...args)
{new (p) T(args...);
}

template<typename T>
void Allocator<T>::Destroy(T *p)
{ p->~T();
}` this is my allocator. I can show vector too, but it's big enough, it doesn't fit in the comment

Comment: Just to test, replace this: `Vector<unsigned char> hex;` with this: `std::vector<unsigned char> hex;`, and remove the `Hex` destructor.  Does your program report memory leaks after that change?  If no memory leaks, then the issue is with your `Vector` class.

Comment: @AleksandrDots -- Edit your original post -- don't put code in the comments.

Comment: @AleksandrDots Your allocator implemenation is wrong. `Deallocate` shouldn't destroy objects, but `delete` does do so. `Deallocate` should only deallocate.

Comment: @AleksandrDots It is also a bit weird that you seem to follow the standard Allocator requirements with regards to the function parameters (e.g. the unused `size_t` parameter in `Deallocate`), but then you do not use the correct spelling of member functions, so that the type isn't usable as standard Allocator. Also, your allocator type (after fixing the issue above) behaves exactly like `std::allocator`. So why do you need to define your own? Is this for any practical purpose or purely academically?

Comment: [`std::allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) has a well defined interface you seem to lightly acknowledge, but also stubbornly ignore.

Comment: @user17732522, yes, in order to use the allocator, the task at the institute was set to implement it yourself.I'll show you my Vector now

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, yes, it works, but i can not use std::vector...

Comment: @AleksandrDots `Vector<T> &Vector<T, Allocator>::operator=(const Vector<T> &other) {` -- Your assignment operator does not deallocate the old memory.  Then it has the flaw of setting member variables *before* `resize()` is called.  What happens if `resize()` is not able to allocate the memory?  You've corrupted your object.

Comment: @user17732522, sorry to bother you, I posted a custom vector. If it's not difficult for you, I would like to know about the error. I just can't understand why the vector works fine, but only when it is not in my Hex class. I am haunted by this question..

Comment: *I just can't understand why the vector works fine* -- It probably was never working "fine".  The `Hex` class exposed the bugs in the Vector class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, but after all, with the help of resize, I reduce or increase the vector if necessary.However , if capacity != other.capacity, then we really didn't allocate memory for it, I fixed it, but it didn't solve the problem . I added this line after resize to reallocate memory if necessary
  this->reserve(other.capacity());

Comment: @AleksandrDots You didn't post `Vector.h`, so this is not a [mcve].  Second, this is off-topic, but your overloaded relation operators `<=`, `>=`, etc. need not be written like that.  All you need is to implement `operator <` and `operator==`, and the rest of the relational operators can be written in terms of `<`.  For example `>` is just `<` with the left and right-side reversed.  As a guide, see [std::rel_ops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, thanks for the advice about operators. I posted Vector.hpp, Allocator.hpp, Allocator.cpp

Comment: Implementing a full fledged vector is an expert programming challenge. There are a lot of challenges that need deep understanding of C++'s dark corners. A rapid glance at your code just reveals too many errors to be possible to fix in a single answer. Lifetime of objects and uninitialized allocations must be properly understood. `std::vector` is a grain of salt in STL; there are just too many details to consider for a complete definition. You should start much lighter, skipping the parts of API meant for optimization only.

Comment: @Red.Wave, The problem was in this constructor. When allocating memory capacity = 0, this memory was not released in the future.Vector<T, A>::Vector() : size_(0), capacity_(0)
{
    data_ = allocator_.Allocate(capacity());
}

Comment: A lot of changes I can see since last time, I viewed your question. I am still holding my position; start small, do everything right, then expand. `std::vector` - like any other STL class - had an overwhelmingly large  and complex API with huge coveray for lots of optimizations. That volume cannot be covered in a single post. `std::vector` doc makes a 200 page book by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this constructor. When allocating memory capacity = 0, this memory was not released in the future
template<class T, class A>

```
Vector<T, A>::Vector() : size_(0), capacity_(0)
{
    data_ = allocator_.Allocate(capacity());
}
```